# Editing a array of objects with a textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a application with AngularJS (1.5)

I'm trying write a component for creating/editing several objects at once via a HTML-Textarea.
I think this might be usefull in differnt cases.

In my application I have arrays like this.

```
var someObjects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'name1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'name2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'name3'
    }
];
```

And I like to fill it into a textarea like this

```
<textarea>
    name1\n
    name2\n
    name3
</textarea>
```

Edits in the textarea should occur in the array.
A new line in the textarea should create a object without id

```
    {
        name: 'name4'
    }
```

The ids are created by the database in the backend.
In my case the application is using data from a rest-api.

The reason to use a textarea- instead of a input-element is, that you can easily add many new objects by adding new lines to the area.
For using input-elements you have to write code to add new inputs and the user has to move the cursor to these

**The Problem**

I know how to populate the textarea with the values with the help of the [ngList](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList)-directive and a toString-function I attach to each object, that returns the name.
But it doesn't work the other way.

When edting the values, the array of objects gets replaced by simple array of strings.
This way I lose additional information like id.

Is there a way to solve the problem?
Does anybody have a idea?

P.S.: here is a quickly hacked plucker to illustrate https://plnkr.co/edit/sbANzvcsNW5oMJPTI813

Comment: Is this for your own use or are random users expected to maintain valid data structure also? If it's the latter I don't see how you can maintain valid structure using a textarea and should use individual `<input>` for each value

Comment: you can split it in your controller, for not mixing AngularJS and pure JS/jQuery code just write simple wrapper as filter

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a text input field for each value?

Comment: i answered some comments in my edit. thanks